# Node w/Express req.session undefined in controller.js

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node, so this may be obvious. In my app's main.js file, I have a route with a call back function that successfully sets the user's session info ( UserID). Basic example :

```
App.get("/setID", function(req,res){
      req.session.UserID = ‘Fred’;
      res.send(“User ID Set”);
 })
```

This works, but I want practice organizing code with routers and controllers. When I move the code to controller.js like this:

```
 Exports.setSessionUserID = function(req,res){
      req.session.UserID = ‘Fred’;
      res.send(“User ID Set”);
 }
```

I get an error that says that req.session is undefined:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'UserID' of undefined.

If I comment out the req.session line, I do get the res.send successfully,  so the router is calling this function correctly.

I belive that controller.js has all of the relevant "requires" (bodyParser, Express-sessions) that are present in main.js.

Why would calling theis function from a controller be any different (regarding sessions) than calling it from main.js?

Comment: Is your session middleware before the router/controller?

Comment: In main.js I use: var session = require("express-sessions") and also do an app.use. I do this all again in controller.js

Comment: Ah ha ! In main.js I do the app.use(sessions...) BEFORE the call to the router! I will rearrange when I get to the office tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it again the controller. Doing app.use() means it will run before all your controllers. Also how are you attaching your controller to your app and in what order?

Comment: Main.js has a require and use to a router.js. . The router.js has a require to the controller.js and then router.get("/setSessionUserID", controller.setSessionUserID).  Module.expoets = router .

Comment: I will reorder the main.js router reference after the session middleware tomorrow (and remove the duplicate references in the controller). That sounds like a good possibility of why main.js works but controller.js version doesn't. Thanks again

Comment: YEP !! The problem was with my router reference being BEFORE the session middleware!!! Lesson learned. . Thanks Pyros !

Answer (score 0):

The only problem here is that you are trying to set a property on `req.session` which itself is `undefined`, and you can't do that

```
// you can do 
Exports.setSessionUserID = function(req,res){
  req.session = { UserId: `Fred` }
  res.send(“User ID Set”);
}
```

An Example

```js
let req = {};
req.session = { UserId: `Fred` };
console.log(req.session.UserId);
```

Comment: Thanks Suman. I see your point, but in my function, "req" references the request object which already has data/members. Req.params will work, but req.session does not. It works fine in main.js but not the controller. What is different between them?

Comment: I see your revision Suman, I will give that a try. Still curious about the difference between main.js and controller.js. thanks again!

Comment: @billw_93720 you are passing `req`, `res` to a function without next I think that's the only problem here.

Comment: I will try adding next. Maybe the controller version of the function needs it while main.js does not. Thanks.

Comment: @billw_93720 to modify `req` use middlewares https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Thanks. I am new at this. I am still confused about middleware vs callback functions. I will make the changes you suggested.